# c/c++ get index of the element which is adding into sorted array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting, indexing

I need function (no implementation, just basic idea)

```
int add(int * array, , const int len, const int val);
```

which is returning index, where the new element ( val ) is stored.
The sorting algorithm is optional but i need the position where the new element is stored.

I can't use STD unfortunately.
Element can have duplicates.

**EDIT:**

The current situation is that i add the new element into last spot, then i run sorting algorithm. So the index is lost during sorting.

Comment: So b-search to find where it belongs, then stuff it in shift-if needed, and return your index. Time to write some code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you rephrase your first sentence in your comment?

Comment: Just for clarity. you want the index it was *inserted* into, right? You're *adding* this element. Correct ? *prior* returned indexes can potentially be invalidated after each insertion. Only the newly inserted item is validly indexed by a return value. You ok with that?

Comment: Don't sort after the insertion. Sort *with* the insertion. Use a binary-search algorithm over the exiting array, find the spot where the new item belongs. make a hole, (shift everything down one slot), and drop the item in. The location where you dropped it is the index, and it is already sorted.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, makes sense, thanks. Still don't know why i am getting downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insertion sort if your Array is already sorted.
 Insertion sort will give the right place for your new item in less complexity.

Else
you can use binary search against your new item in array to find the proper place in array.
after that shift all other element to make the place for new item.